# How to get window width in multiple window mode Android 7?

Tags: android, size, screen

Since Android 7.0 we have multiple window mode. See example in this picture:

[image]

User can change the width of window.

How can I get the real width of window?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Sorry, but I still cannot find out how to get the screen width

Answer (score 1):

You can register on decoration view change by adding a layout observer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Log.d("Main Activity", "" + getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight());
        Log.d("Main Activity", "" + getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth());
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

```
Activity yourActivity = ...
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int windowWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```